# I have create a custom menu in frontend in magento 2

Tags: magento

using code

```
 <a href="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl()."become-a-reseller.phtml"; ?>" class="level-top ui-corner-all"  role="menuitem" >
     <span><?php echo __("Become A Reseller")?></span>     
 </a>
```

in **topmenu.phtml** file . and i want to redirect this href to become-a-reseller.phtml file which is located at `app/design/my_theme/dreamshop/magento_theme/templates/html` folder   then what should be the path in anchor tag href

Comment: you have to check path in xml file it not based on phtml file physical path. Please check frontend path in xml file.

Comment: okay.  app/design/my_theme/dreamshop/magento_theme/layout/defult.xml  here  give the reference of block .   Actually I am new to magento 2 ... So i don't know much more about it .

Comment: I Added a custom menu in frontend . and i want to link file on that menu

Comment: In magento 2 you will found `routes.xml` file and in that file you can find `<route id="inchootest" frontName="inchootest">` and frontname is your url.